# Can't Rollback Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I made some changes to my ASP.NET MVC 4 project that introduced a bug, so I wanted to rollback my project to the last check-in.  This check-in works; it doesn't have any broken code.  So I used the "Get Specific Version" option, navigated to my last check-in, and rolled it back.

It doesn't revert my code to my last check-in's code.  It just puts a little red check mark next to all of the files that contain my broken code with a tooltip saying "Checked out to me".

So I decided to rollback to my very first check-in.  Some conflicts auto-resolve; I keep all of the server's versions of files when it prompts me to.  It doesn't revert my code to my very first check-in's code.  What am I missing; how do I load the code from my last successful check-in?

Comment: You probably have to revert any local changes you've made.

Comment: I'm trying to revert the local changes I've made.

Comment: tf undo *<folder or filename>*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to fix this myself: after navigating to View > Team Explorer, I had eight Pending Changes that were hidden.  Manually right-clicking these and selecting "Undo" reverted the files to the last successful check-in.  Pretty basic stuff, but I figured I would post an answer rather than deleting my question entirely, because the process is a little confusing for a beginner (like myself).